# Slim giving 404 when requesting Head, but 200 on curl -i

Tags: curl, nginx, slim

On my slim project, i've an resource like (/products/abc.json) and i'm mapping this in my nginx conf (like *.json to api.php) and then, on api.php i'm setting up a resource.It's working when requesting the content of api but not HEAD.

when i'm doing :

```
curl -I
```

it gives 404 but not;

```
curl -i
```

I've tried so much things, but couldn't manage to solve.

Thanks